# UIbutton autoresizing

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have a simple UIImageView with some button. When I rotate the iPad simulator, buttons don't resize. How can I fix it?

P.S: I'm using Xcode 4.5, which as you know, does not have autoresizing mask (that canvas in size inspector which we simply click on arrows and do the masking) in interface builder, which were included before.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question but, if you want the autoresizing mask back, turn off Autolayout in the File Inspector for the xib or storyboard you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```